# Identifying the Tenant based on sub-domain before login on ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to get the .NET full framework version of the MVC sample Boilerplate to identify the tenant based on the URL on landing. Ideally when a user lands on their login page, we should set the tenant for them, and if possible I'd like to customize the page.

I.E. going to tenant1.myDomain.com should set you up to login as tenant 1, tenant2.myDomain.com to tenant 2, etc etc..

Working with a clean/fresh template downloaded Friday.

.NET Full 4.6.1
ABP 4.2.0

Deployed onto an IIS 7.5 Server. Website is working fine.

Based on the Current Tenant Documentation [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#determining-current-tenant), the MultiTenancy should be looking to the subdomain to identify the tenant.

I've tried using both:

```
"App": {
    "WebSiteRootAddress": "http://{TENANCY_NAME}.myDomain.com"
  },
```

and

```
"App": {
     "WebSiteRootAddress": "{TENANCY_NAME}.myDomain.com"
  },
```

in the appsettings.json.

Regardless of the configuration I attempt, the site always tries to log in as the Host rather than a tenant. I am sure I can override this on page load, but based on everything I am seeing in other comments I feel like this feature is already implemented somewhere in the APB codebase.

Comment: Try adding a slash at the end.

Comment: Thanks @aaron but no luck / no difference.

Comment: Did you find a solution, I have the same issue?